# JS function logs answer but returns "undefined"

Tags: javascript, function, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to do a lookup in a 2d array in vanilla JS.

```
    ["fruit","apple","orange","grape","banana","peach"],
    ["veg", "cucumber", "carrot", "eggplant","lettuce","tomato","cabbage","bean"],
    ["flower", "rose", "carnation", "orchid"],
    ["color", "red","green","blue","cyan","yellow","magenta","black","white"],
    ["aircraft","monoplane","biplane","helicopter","hot air balloon", "gas balloon","autogyro","airship","sailplane","powerlift"]
];

let mytopic = "color";

const choose = topic => {
    choices.forEach(row => {
        if (row[0] == topic) {
            var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (row.length - 1)) + 1;
            console.log(row[index]);
            return row[index];
        }
    });
};

alert(choose(mytopic));
```

The expected answer appears in the console, but the alert always shows "undefined".

I know this has to be something annoyingly simple, but after searching for an hour here and on MDN, I'm completely baffled.

...and yes, I know tomato is really a fruit.

Comment: yeah, so, `choose` returns nothing. Returning from a forEach loop callback isn't returning from the parent function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `return` statement is for your inner function starting with `row =>`, which won't do anything. `forEach` doesn't return anything by design, and your function itself has no return statement either.

One way to rewrite this is to find the row and then work with it. You can't short circuit a `forEach` with a `return` statement, it will still execute for every element in the array.

```
const choose = topic => {
    const row = choices.find(row => row[0] == topic);
    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (row.length - 1)) + 1;
    console.log(row[index]);
    return row[index];
};
```

Comment: Thanks!  So it was the find method I was missing!